# Dot plot from list with Plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, plotly, graphviz

I have a Pandas Serie S, with

```
Index Number
A    10 
B    13
C    14
D    23
```

My target is to make a dot plot of this list with python.

I'm following this tuto : [with plotly](https://plot.ly/python/dot-plots/)

However, I don't understand how to go from my serie to the viz.

I tried the following :

```
fig = px.scatter(s, x="number", y="index",
                 title="Title")

fig.show()
```

But nothing happens.

What is wrong in my process to go to the plotly dot plot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the tutorial you could save the data in a dataframe and plot it

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
output_notebook()
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

S = pd.Series([10, 13, 14, 23], index=['A','B','C','D'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'index' : S.index,
                    'values': S.values})
fig = px.scatter(df, x="index", y="values")
fig.show()
```

Comment: I'm using Spyder
When i do this transformation and then fig.show(), nothing happens (no error, nothing), just next "in [x]"

Comment: Try the code in a jupyter notebook and check if it works. I think the problem is probably related to Spyder. Check if there are some specifics for using plotly in a non-webbased enviroment